Keepout Filter alternative for Foxy
I was trying to use the Keepout Filter plugin for Nav2 with ROS2 Foxy to add some zones where my robot couldn't be, before realizing it's not available in this distro. Is there any way to achieve similar functionality without having to upgrade to Humble?
